# java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 400 : Bad Request

Tags: json, spring-boot, facebook-graph-api, java-8, httpurlconnection

I am having following piece of code:

```
URL url = new URL(baseUrl);
    HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    conn.setDoOutput(true);
    conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
    conn.setRequestProperty("Authorisation", "Bearer "+socialMedia.getFacebookPage_Token());
    String payload = "{\"name\":\""+segment.getName()+"\","
            + "\"subtype\":\"CUSTOM\","
            + "\"description\":\"Bingage Custom Audience\","
            + "\"customer_file_source\":\"USER_PROVIDED_ONLY\"}";
    OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream(), "UTF-8");
    writer.write(payload);
    writer.close();
    if (conn.getResponseCode() != 200) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed : HTTP error code : "
                + conn.getResponseCode()+"  :  " +conn.getResponseMessage());
    }
```

I have checked data is getting populated properly. But when I make request I get following exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed : HTTP error code : 400  :  Bad Request
at com.wallet.service.impl.SocialMediaServiceImpl.createCustomAudience(SocialMediaServiceImpl.java:218)
at com.wallet.service.impl.SocialMediaServiceImpl.createOrUpdateCustomAudience(SocialMediaServiceImpl.java:185)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333)
at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
```

If I post same data with `Postman` it works like charm. I would like to know what I am doing wrong over here ?

I have also tried payload like this:

```
JSONObject data = new JSONObject();
    data.put("name", segment.getName());
    data.put("subtype", "CUSTOM");
    data.put("description", "Bingage Custom Audience");
    data.put("customer_file_source", "USER_PROVIDED_ONLY");
    writer.write(data.toString());
```

thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this what makes you fail but you misspelled **Authorization** header